# Ansible: 'debug' 'msg' formatting required

Tags: ansible

```yaml
- name: Set facts for later use
  hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

    - name: set facts
      set_fact:
        hosts: "{{ ansible_fqdn }}"

    - name: print
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hosts }}"
```

The script above results in three hosts. I want the hosts to be formatted as `host1.example.com,host2.example.com,host3.example.com` to be later used in the script elsewhere.

How can this be achieved?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given the variables *ansible_fqdn* declared in an inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host1 ansible_fqdn=host1.example.com
host2 ansible_fqdn=host2.example.com
host3 ansible_fqdn=host3.example.com
```

Extract the variables from the [*hostvars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables). See [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)

```yaml
  hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_fqdn') }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
  hosts:
  - host1.example.com
  - host2.example.com
  - host3.example.com
```

Now, you can format the list

```yaml
  {{ hosts|join(',') }}
```

gives the string

```bash
  host1.example.com,host2.example.com,host3.example.com
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_fqdn') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: hosts
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ hosts|join(',') }}
      run_once: true
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
  - name: Create hosts string
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      hosts: "{{ groups['all'] | join(',') }}"
```

Change `['all']` to your specific group if you need

Comment: If the inventory grows, or the play has less hosts in it, the fact you're setting would become invalid.

Comment: inventory size has no effect on the variable

Comment: Ofcourse it will. Prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> *The script above results in three hosts.*

According [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) these can be considered as [`ansible_play_hosts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_play_hosts).

> *I want the hosts to be formatted as*

Therefore a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show Play Hosts
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all | join(',') }}"
```

will result into the requested output as the

> *List of all the hosts that were targeted by the play*

are already provided within that list.